# How can I increase the font size in Interface Builder

Tags: xcode, macos, interface-builder

Is it possible to increase the font size in Interface Builder? The ridiculously small side of those fonts, specially on the Inspector, are giving me headaches.

Comment: I think your only option is to use the OS X built-in zoom feature (Command-Option-8 to turn on/off, Command-Option-Minus to zoom out, Command-Option-Plus to zoom in).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using the wonderful AppleDisplayScaleFactor, but I wouldn't be very surprised if a lot of things stopped working correctly. So it will correctly increase the font size (along with everything else), but the headaches would probably remain. Or get much, much worse. But hey, you asked!

```
defaults write com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3 AppleDisplayScaleFactor 1.2
```

Comment: This feature isn't ready for prime time. I couldn't recommend it.

Comment: Actually it doesn't "sort of work". See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4099151/interface-builder-hangs-while-dragging-a-slider/4248319#4248319

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately no. [File an enhancement request.](http://bugreport.apple.com)