# Interface Builder hangs while dragging a slider

Tags: cocoa, macos, interface-builder

Every time I drag a vertical or horizontal slider, Interface Builder 3.2.4 hangs.

Is anyone else having this same problem? Any fixes?

Comment: Try running Spin Control while you do this; this will get you samples of the hang, so you may be able to see what it's thinking about.

Comment: I did as you recommended, but it doesn't make much sense to me. Does this mean something to you?
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3978473/spincontrol.txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found out the problem: I had previously changed the AppleDisplayScaleFactor of IB to 1.1 to reduce the eye-sore. after setting it back to 1.0, the hangs disappeared.

Of course, now I have to deal with the ridiculously small font sizes...